# how can i open one jsp page from another jsp page via jquery in spring mvc

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

Below is my jquery code from which i wan't to open editPostion.jsp page in spring mvc.

```
$('#editRAG').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            cache: false,
            //dataType : 'json',
            url : "editPosition.jsp",
            data: {
                posn : $('#RAGVal').val(),  
            },
            success : function(data) {alert('2');
                window.location="/editPosition.jsp"                   
                }
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know what a link is?from what i see you don't know what ajax is used for

Answer (score 1):

Don't access JSPs from the client directly. Instead, rely on a controller to serve you the JSP.

For example, you may have a controller mapped to a GET request to `/editPosition` that serves you the `editPosition.jsp`. In such a case, access the `/editPosition` URL in your AJAX call instead.

Comment: thanks for the help...but did i need to send request to the controller through jquery?? if yes, how??

Comment: Please read my second paragraph again; it's about how to send a request to the controller. EDIT: If you're having trouble with Spring basics, you might want to try a tutorial, for example: https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Answer (score 0):

Define a controller with a handler method in it which would return to client the "view" which would render your jsp.
There are configurations that you required to do it in your spring mvc.

1.Configure application-context.xml for view resolver, in your case *.jsp

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

2. Add controller with handler method to return you the required view on GET, i.e. editPosition.jsp

   ```
    @Controller
    public class ViewController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/position", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getEditPositionView(){
       return new ModelAndView("editPosition");
    }
   }
   ```
3. Your jQuery should look like (partially)

   ```
   $('#editRAG').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
       type : "GET",
       cache: false,
       content-type: application/json
       url : "position", //server root + position 
       data: {
           posn : $('#RAGVal').val(),  
       }
     }); 
    });
   ```